# nth-derivative of a function of n

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am trying to evaluate a find a residue at $i$, $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{({z+i})^n{(z-i)}^{n}}$

I used the definition for residues for repeated roots (assume n is greater than one). I have written it out, but now I am stuck by the derivative, because the number inside the derivative is correlated to how many times to take the derivative.

$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to i} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left(\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^n}\right)
$$

Comment: It seems that you want to compute a residue. It is probably simpler to substitute $w=z+i$ and look at the power series of $\dfrac{e^{iw}}{w^n}$.

Comment: $z=i$ is not a pole, so what is the point of taking this limit, and not just the value at $z=i$?

Comment: @AnneBauval  It is probably an intermediate computation; it corresponds to the residue of $\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+1)^n}$ at $z = i$.

Comment: @Abezhiko Your residue is $0.$

Comment: @Skyttesen: did you mean $\lim_{z\to\color{red}-i}$ (as Martin seemed to take for granted in his comment)? If so, please edit your post, to 1) correct it 2) [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): include some work (just follow Martin's advice), and explain where you are stuck. Or if it helped you to find the (quite easy) solution, edit it as a [self answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I'm going to try and do the power series expansion and see where I get. This is my first time on stackexchange so I am getting used to the way things work. Sorry.

Comment: Martin's hint won't help if you really mean $z\to i$ and not $z\to-i.$ And again, if you mean $z\to i,$ why write a limit, which is just the value?

Comment: I was just basing it off the calculation of Residues for poles of higher order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles
I'm thinking about trying different series expansion to find the residue, maybe that'll be easier than the residue formula

Comment: But again (as mentionned in my 2 first comments): $z=i$ is *not* a pole of $g(z):=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^n},$ so $\lim_{z\to i}g^{(n-1)}(z)=g^{(n-1)}(i)$.

Comment: Okay sure, how does that help with simplification though? I'm still trying to use a series expansion to simplify it (maybe because the derivative will have a pattern?).

Answer (score 1):

Let us calculate the Taylor series around $z=i$ of
$$g(z):=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+i)^n}.$$
For $|h|<2,$
$$\begin{align}g(i+h)&=\frac{e^{i(i+h)}}{(2i+h)^n}\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}}{(2i)^n}\,\frac{e^{ih}}{\left(1+\frac h{2i}\right)^n}\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}}{(2i)^n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ih)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty{n+j-1\choose j}\left(-\frac h{2i}\right)^j.
\end{align}$$
The coefficient of $h^{n-1}$ is
$$\begin{align}\frac1{(n-1)!}g^{(n-1)}(i)&=\frac{e^{-1}}{(2i)^n}\sum_{j+k=n-1}\frac{i^k}{k!}{n+j-1\choose j}\left(-\frac 1{2i}\right)^j\\&=
\frac{e^{-1}}{2^ni}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1+j)!}{(n-1-j)!j!}\left(-\frac 12\right)^j
\\&=
\frac1{2^nie}y_{n-1}(-1),\end{align}$$
where $y_m$ is the $m$-th [Bessel polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials).

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be $y_{n-1} (1)$ ? Also it seems like the $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ was dropped but that's a quick fix

Comment: No @Skyttesen it is $y_{n-1} (-1)$ (what makes you believe it should be $y_{n-1} (1)$?)   and the factorial was cancelled by differentiating $h^{n-1}$ $(n-1)$ times.

Comment: Does the Taylor series not have a $(-1)^{j}$ term? that'll combine with the $-1$ in the $(-\frac{1}{2i})^{j}$ does it not?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you. My Taylor series does have a $(-1)^j$ as part of $ (-\frac{h}{2i})^{j}
$ (I used https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formule_du_binôme_négatif)       , but it "combines" with nothing. It *becomes* "the $-1$ in $(-\frac{1}{2i})^{j}$".

Comment: @Skyttesen $$\forall n\in\Bbb N,\quad(1+z)^{-n}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}{n+j-1\choose j}(-z)^j.$$Are you still doubting something?

Comment: Yeah that's correct, my bad. However, it still appears to be flawed because when I check the integral (this is part of solving an integral using contour integration), the values don't match up with your solution. Specifically, $2\pi i$ times the value in my question should be equal to $\frac{7}{8} \frac{\pi}{e}$, but that doesn't work with your solution which is weird.

Comment: I don't see any flaw in my answer, and I (or we) cannot help without more details on how your $\frac{7\pi}{8e\cdot2\pi i}$ is related to the question in your post.